# Ag Grid Enterprise features

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using `ag-grid-enterprise`

**app.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { LicenseManager } from "ag-grid-enterprise"

LicenseManager.setLicenseKey('<enterprisekey>')
...
```

**DataGrid.js**

```
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react'
import 'ag-grid-enterprise'
import React from 'react'

class DataGrid extends React.Component {


    onGridReady = params => {
     this.gridApi = params.api
     this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi
     console.log('params', params) // ag-grid enterprise features are null E.G.(aggFuncService, clipboardService)
    }

    render() {

    return (
          // Props omitted for brevity
          <AgGridReact />
    )
  }

 }
```

**package.json**

```
{
"ag-grid": "18.1.1",
"ag-grid-community": "^19.1.1",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "^19.1.1",
"ag-grid-react": "18.1.0",
}
```

Why `ag-grid-react` **enterprise** features are null? It seems i am doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First:
remove [obsolete npm package `ag-grid`](https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-changelog/?fixVersion=19.0.0)

> Breaking Changes:
>
> The NPM package name for the free module of ag-Grid is now `ag-grid-community` instead of `ag-grid`. This means you install with `npm install ag-grid-community` and then you reference like `import {Grid, GridOptions} from "ag-grid-community"`.

Then: 
Update `ag-grid-react` to same version as `ag-grid-community`

And the last one, not sure what exactly you are trying to find in `params`, but if your license is valid you should be able to use all features.

> simple check: just add [`[enableRangeSelection]="true"`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-range-selection/#example-range-selection) in `gridOptions` and try to select range among rows+columns